# How to make a dhcp server using busybox udhcpd for multiple ports

Tags: debian

I have a Beaglebone Black that needs to be configured as a DHCP SERVER:

I want BOTH [eth0 and usb0] to act as a DHCP SERVER once clients connect to them via a standard cable, crossover (no router/hub) and usb.

Ex: 3 Beaglebones. Beaglebone#1 is the DHCP SERVER, Beaglebone#2 & #3 are the clients - 1 of them will connect to #1 using USB0 & the other ETH0, both are waiting for an IP to be issued to them.

Is this possible?
eth0 = 169.254.y.z; no dmesg-log errors; 0.0.0.0udp-68 but no udp-67 & no dhcp service loaded.

System Setup:
Linux Debian Jessie 4.4(ti-variant)

Comment: What challenges are you having setting up the DHCP server that way?  Is the DHCP server running?  Are there any errors in the log?  Is anything listening on port 67, and on appropriate addresses?

Comment: eth0 = 169.254.y.z; no dmesg-log errors; 0.0.0.0udp-68 but no udp-67 & no *dhcp* loaded!

Comment: Instead of using comments, could you please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/288167/edit) your question to include the extra information?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got my answer: The service wasn't running because the interfaces were down.
First to fix interface:

```
ifconfig eth0 up

ifconfig usb0 up
```

Second, uninstall any other DHCPDaemons except uDHCPD to free up udp port 67. Use:

```
netstat -tulnp |grep :67
```

If nothing comes up, its uDHCPD is not running; you'll have to start it:

http://xmodulo.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-access-point.html

If you want to bridge them together after you're done:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge

the BEST I can do for those hurting as I was. ~ Eric Renouf and Beagleboy
(thanks Eric)